# div inside script tag throws exception - why

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert a template into DOM using jQuery but it gives me the error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. Why so?

Works fine:

```
$('body').children().last().after('<div></div>');
```

Throws exception:

```
$('body').children().last().after('<script><div></div></script>');
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `<div></div>` is not valid JavaScript. jQuery is trying to generate a `<script>` element with the innerHTML of `<div></div>`.

<s>Note that your approach is probably wrong. Please see **[What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166899)**</s>

If you want to use `text/template` templates, you have to include that in the `<script>` element's attributes:

```
$('body').children().last().after('<script type="text/template"><div></div></script>');
```

Comment: Thnaks, so how can I fix it? I'm not falling into XY problem since I've said what I'm trying to do `I'm trying to insert a template into DOM using jQuery`

Comment: What kind of template? You mean `<script type="text/template">` kind of template? If that's the case, you need to specify the type.

Comment: That's it - `type="text/template"` - thanks! It did the trick. I've always thought that this attribute is purely informative and it turns out that it's also functional.

Comment: `<script>` is `type="text/javascript"` by default, which is why it can often be omitted. That's not the case with other MIME types.